# How do you effectively compare 15000 files multiple times?

Tags: compare

I am comparing two almost identical folders which include hidden .svn folders which should be ignored and I want to continually quickly compare the folders as some files are patched to compared the difference without checking the unchanged matching files again.

edit:
Because there are so many options I'm interested in a solution that clearly exploits the knowledge from the previous compare because any other solution is not really feasable when doing repeated comparisons.

Comment: Mr. Period, your friend at the end.  He tells you when it's ok to breathe.

Comment: An SVN hook to notify you of changes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are willing to spend a bit of money, Beyond Compare is a pretty powerful diffing tool that can do folder based diffing.

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/)

Comment: This tool is your friend.  And it's not that expensive, considering how wonderful it is.

Comment: the breakfast^h^h^hcomparison tool of champions +1

Answer (score 7):

I personally use [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) and find it very useful. It has filters that exclude svn file. Under linux i prefer [Meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to use `rsync`.  Something like:

```
rsync -n -r -v -C dir_a dir_b
```

The `-n` option does a dry-run so no files will be modified.  `-r` does a recursive comparison.  Optionally turn on verbose mode with `-v`.  (You could use `-i` to itemize the changes instead of `-v`.)  To ignore commonly ignored files such as `.svn/` use `-C`.

This should be faster than a simple `diff` as I read the `rsync` manpage:

> Rsync  finds  files  that  need to be transferred using a "quick check"
>          algorithm (by default) that looks for files that have changed  in  size
>          or   in  last-modified  time.   Any  changes  in  the  other  preserved
>          attributes (as requested by options) are made on the  destination  file
>          directly  when  the quick check indicates that the file's data does not
>          need to be updated.

Since the "quick check" algorithm does not look at file contents directly, it might be fooled.  In that case, the `-c` option, which performs a checksum instead, may be needed.  It is likely to be faster than an ordinary `diff`.

In addition, if you plan on syncing the directories at some point, this is a good tool for that job as well.

Comment: rsync is good for this, once you learned how to use it. Especially if you sync the folders, then you can avoid repeated compares.

Answer (score 1):

Not foolproof, but you could just compare the timestamps.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work if the timestamps weren't identical to begin with.

Comment: If you record the time stamps as some point and then compare them to your record later, you'd know which files have changed in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Use total commander ! All the cool developers use it :)

Comment: Synchronize Dirs..

also by content and asymmetric folders

Comment: totalcommander is good for doing interactive compare and sync. I would not knopw how to do things automagically with total commander - that is why I prefer to use rsync.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on linux or some variant, you should be able to do:

prompt$ diff -r dir1 dir2 --exclude=.svn

The -r forces recursive lookups.  There are a bunch of switches to ignore stuff like whitespace etc.